# Display the seconds of TMediaPlayer.Duration and TMediaPlayer.CurrentTime using Delphi for Android

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio, tmediaplayer

I'm using Delphi 10.3 for developing android mobile application. I'm using the TMediaPlayer to play the mp3 files. I want to display the current time and remaining time of the currently playing media file with the minutes and seconds (mm:ss - ref: VLC media player). But I can able display the minutes properly and I want to display the seconds with the two digits.

Please help me to display the seconds properly.

Here, I have mentioned the code that I have tried.

```
procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TrackBar1.Tag := 1;
  TrackBar1.Value := MediaPlayer1.CurrentTime;
  CurrentMin := MediaPlayer1.CurrentTime div 1000 div 600000;
  CurrentSec := MediaPlayer1.CurrentTime div 1000; // Seconds
  DurationMin := MediaPlayer1.Duration div 1000 div 600000;
  DurationSec := MediaPlayer1.Duration div 1000; // Seconds
  LabelCurrentTime.Text   := Format('%2.2d : %2.2d', [CurrentMin, CurrentSec]);
  LabelRemainingTime.Text := Format('%2.2d : %2.2d', [DurationMin, DurationSec]);
  TrackBar1.Tag := 0;  
end;
```

Comment: You neglected to mention what the output is that you are seeing, and what the variables are declared as. Regardless, assuming that they're integers, you could use: `Format('%d:%.2d', [CurrentMin, CurrentSec])`, which should result in strings like "9:45" and "3:06", for example

Answer (score 5):

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FMX.Media.TMediaPlayer.CurrentTime) for FMX.Media.TMediaPlayer.CurrentTime says:

> CurrentTime is measured in 100ns. To obtain s, divide `CurrentTime` by `MediaTimeScale`. (s refers to seconds)

and

> `MediaTimeScale: Integer = $989680;`

So, given variables

```
var
  CurrentTime, RemainingTime: int64;
  CurMins, CurSecs, RemMins, RemSecs: integer;
```

we can write the following

```
  CurrentTime := MediaPlayer1.CurrentTime;
  RemainingTime := MediaPlayer1.Duration - CurrentTime;

  CurMins := CurrentTime div MediaTimeScale div 60;
  CurSecs := CurrentTime div MediaTimeScale mod 60;
  LabelCurrentTime.Text := Format('Current: %d:%.2d',[CurMins, CurSecs]);

  RemMins := RemainingTime div MediaTimeScale div 60;
  RemSecs := RemainingTime div MediaTimeScale mod 60;
  LabelRemainingTime.Text := Format('Remaining: %d:%.2d',[RemMins, RemSecs]);
```

Note the usage of 'mod' to limit seconds display to '00 .. 59'

Comment: @test12345 You do know, don't you, that you can mark correct answers  by clicking green the tick mark beside the answer, and optionally upvote / downvote by using the up / down arrow buttons.